# Assembly movf & movwf

Tags: assembly

i will realize my circuit with my PIC16F84A from Microchip... so i have to put a signal from `PORTA,3` to `PORTB,0` but movwf is just working with `PORTB`... i have following code

```
movf        PORTA,3   ; copy PORTA,3 into registry
movwf       PORTB,0   ; copy PORTA,3 from the registry into PORTB,0
```

so... when i give a high on `PORTA,3` it should be give a signal on `PORTB,0`....

how can i realize that?

Answer (score 1):

This should move the value of `PORTA` to `PORTB`:

```
movf PORTA, W
movwf PORTB
```

It's a bit unclear from your question whether you want to move the value as-is, or if you want to set bit 0 of `PORTB` to bit 3 of `PORTA`. In the latter case you can do something like this (written in C since I don't know the exact PIC16 syntax off the top of my head):

```
temp = PORTA;
temp >>= 3; 
temp &= 1;      // temp now contains PORTA.0 in bit 0
temp2 = PORTB;
temp2 &= ~1;    // clear bit 0, keep all others as-is
temp |= temp2;
PORTB = temp;
```

Comment: i want to set the bit 0 from `PORTA` to the bit 3 on `PORTB`... clear enough? :D

Answer (score 1):

Moving signal PORTA(3) to PORTB(0):

```
btfss PORTA,3
bcf PORTB,0
btfsc PORTA,3
bsf PORTB,0
```

Edit:

```
// if PORT(3) is zero, PORTB(0,1,2) is reset to zero
movlw f8
btfss PORTA,3
andwf PORTB,1

// if PORT(3) is set, PORTB(0,1,2) is set to high
movlw 03
btfsc PORTA,3
iorwf PORTB,1
```

Comment: this works, but just a little bit.... if i set a high signal on `PORTA,3` it gives a high signal on `PORTB,0`... so this works fine... but on `PORTB,1` and `PORTB,2` is an high signal too? how can i fix that?

Comment: So, you want like, if `PORTA(3`) is high, `PORTB(0)`, `PORTB(1)` and `PORTB(2)` is set high, right?

Comment: no if i set `PORTA,3` high should just `PORTB,0` are be high... your code works fine... but when i set `PORTA,3` high is `PORTB,0` and 1 and 2 high.... i think this is a mistake....

Comment: so... is `PORTA,3` high `PORTB,0` must be set high... that's it ;) and thanks